# ¿"Haber + participio" actúa exclusivamente como verbo?

Tags: adjetivos, participio, categorías-gramaticales, verbos-auxiliares, haber

Según entiendo, el participio pasado puede actuar como adjetivo, o como verbo, como parte de una perifrasis verbal. De hecho es muy común encontrarla con el verbo "haber".  Por ejemplo:

> Él **ha subido** la montaña.
>
> Ellos **han caminado** mucho.
>
> Ella se **ha reído** mucho.
>
> Yo **he estudiado** bastante.

Según mi apreciación en todos estos casos el participio pasado **NO** presenta ningún efecto como adjetivo, y se limita a formar una perifrasis verbal donde sirve como verbo principal, y "haber" sirve como verbo auxiliar (vease [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=haber) inciso **3** "verbo auxiliar").

¿Estoy en lo correcto?  ¿Siempre ocurre lo mismo al combinar "haber"+"participio"?

Comment: Es posible que en tiempos antiguos que el verbo haber funcionase como tener (vamos, eso sí). Así, como podemos decir «tenemos hecho/s el/los trabajo/s» con el participio en función de adjetivo, asI habría sido con haber.

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, el participio en este caso es simplemente parte de la construcción perifrástica y no funciona como adjetivo. Una forma sencilla de advertir la diferencia es que el participio, en esta construcción, es invariable: aparece siempre en la forma que (en un adjetivo) llamaríamos masculina del singular (terminada en *-ado, -ido* si es regular).

El participio aparece con género y número variables en la construcción perifrástica de la voz pasiva. (*La montaña fue escalad**a*** vs. *Las montañas fueron escalad**as*** vs. *Los montes fueron escalad**os**.*) También es variable en ciertas construcciones que usan *tener* o *llevar*, como por ejemplo: *Ya tengo hecha mi tarea de toda la semana*, *Llevo perdidos tres días con esto.* Estas construcciones son semánticamente cercanas a la del tiempo verbal compuesto con *haber*, pero no idénticas.

El uso de *haber* como auxiliar data del latín tardío; antes el verbo significaba "tener", pero después comenzó a reducirse y a incorporarse a otras construcciones, como ésta que mencionamos, la del futuro simple y la del condicional.

---

Aclaración: En los ejemplos sobre la montaña, el participio funciona como un adjetivo.

Comment: @pablodt76 Gracias por la respuesta, pero perdona, solo para estar seguro de que te comprendí; en tu segundo parrafo, los ejemplos respecto a la montaña escalada, en todos estos casos el participio SI tiene efecto de adjetivo, ¿o he entendi mal?

Comment: Pablo, given the agreement requirement (*concordancia*), does that mean the past participle is being used as an *adjective* in your mountain examples?   I think that's what OP was getting at.

Comment: Bit late, but replying: yes. En los ejemplos sobre la montaña, el participio funciona como un adjetivo.

Answer (score 0):

Existe otra manera de combinar "haber"+"participio".  Un ejemplo:

- Su esposa, habiendo puesto el caldo a calentar, fue a la sala a hacer una llamada telefónica importante.

Quizás esto se puede considerar como adjetivo.